# Downloading from a URL gives an aspx page instead of the actual file

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium to open a URL in Chrome and hit a button, which will download a text file for me. But it's giving me an aspx page instead of the text file.

It's working fine if I do this manually in Chrome.
I also tried to do this with a Firefox driver but I got the same issue.

I am opening the url `using driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()`.

Can you guys please help me on this?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Have got a code that is run under the button or is it external resource that you don't have any control?

Comment: You can use different approaches from this place: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver

Comment: There is no error.It's just downloading as ASPX page instead of the txt file!